# How to buffer subscribed topic?

Tags: ros, buffer, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's suppose node A subscribe the topic published by node B. Node A do many caculatations for the subscribed data, it will take a lot of time.  However, node B publish topic too fast and assume we can not change the publish rate. So many data published by node B can not be subscribed on time. These data will be lost.

So is there any method to buffer the subscribed topic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198415/how-to-buffer-subscribed-topic?/) by [somebodyus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20767/somebodyus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2014-11-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One easy way is to increase  queue size of subscriber.

```
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("topic_name", 1000, subscriber_callback);  //  queue size is 1000
```

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [somebodyus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20767/somebodyus/) on 2014-12-01**:
How to do that using command?  I can not modify the source file.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-12-02**:
You should change in source code. I dont think its possible from command line.